# I need batch commnad to findstr and retrieve text to the end of text file

Tags: batch-file, command

I need batch commnad to findstr and retrieve text to the end of text file.

text file include

```
  #  failure         detail                           
                                                      
 1.  AssertionError  Response time is less than 100ms 
                     expected false to be truthy      
                     at assertion:1 in test-script    
                     inside "epos-agentDetailsInfo"   
   
 2.  AssertionError  Response time is less than 100ms 
                     expected false to be truthy      
                     at assertion:1 in test-script    
                     inside "epos-getccounts"
```

I  need to find "AssertionError"  and retrieve text to the end of text file.

I  expect to show  since "AssertionError"  untill  the end of file.

I  try this.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "AssertionError" test1.log') do set "uniuser=%%a"  
echo User is: %uniuser%   

endlocal
```

and it 's show only  " 2.   AssertionError  Response time is less than 100ms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is what you need:

It's not clear whether the empty lines in your data are actually empty, or contain one, two, or more spaces. The code caters for any pf these situations.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74454843.txt"
SET "outfile=%sourcedir%\q74454843.rpt"

SET "repro="

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%b IN ('find /n /v "" ^<"%filename1%"') DO (
 SET "mtline=%%c"
 IF DEFINED mtline CALL SET "mtline=%%mtline: =%%"
 IF DEFINED mtline (
  IF DEFINED repro (
   ECHO %%c
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO %%c|FINDSTR /L /C:"AssertionError" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "repro=Y"&ECHO %%c)
  )
 ) ELSE (
 IF DEFINED repro ECHO.
 SET "repro="
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

`repro` is a flag to determine whether to reproduce the line or not.

Each line is numbered with a leading `[linenumber]` by the `find` so the part before the `]` is assigned to `%%b` and the actual line contents to `%%c`.

`mtline` is then used as substringing metavariables (like `%%c`) is not supported; it receives a copy of `%%c` and if this is not empty, removes any spaces.

if `mtline` is then empty, batch interprets it as `undefined`.

if `mtline` is defined, the code then determines whether `repro` is defined and `echo`es `%%c` if it is defined, otherwise it asks `findstr` whether the line contains the target string; if it does, then set `repro` to a value (making it `defined` and `echo` the line.

if `mtline` is not defined, then we have reached the end of the section, so `echo` an empty line and clear `repro` so no further lines are reproduced.

The `^<` is an `escaped redirector` which tells `cmd` that the redirector is part of the `find` command, not the `for`.

The entire `for` command is enclosed in parentheses so that the `echo`es it executes can be redirected to a file.

Comment: one question  output   it can be retreive to variable ?

Comment: Batch does not support more than one physical line in a variable. It would be possible to create a pseudo-array with line[1]=first report line,line[2]=second report line and so on or they could be combined so report[1]=line1+line2+line3 (of the first error report), report[2]=... (of the second error report) where report[n] could either be serially assigned (ie. from 1) or could be the number in "column #".